# YCSB can't load data

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I use YCSB-0.1.3 to test Hbase 0.96, there is one server and three slaves and I configure my YCSB reffered to this blog:
http://blog.lars-francke.de/2010/08/16/performance-testing-hbase-using-ycsb/

However, when I tried to load workload, I get the following result:

```
[hbase@com YCSB]$ java -cp build/ycsb.jar:db/hbase/lib/* com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -load -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=family -p recordcount=1000 -s > load.dat
Loading workload...

Starting test.
 0 sec: 0 operations;
 10 sec: 0 operations; 
 20 sec: 0 operations; 
 30 sec: 0 operations; 
 40 sec: 0 operations; 
 50 sec: 0 operations; 
 60 sec: 0 operations; 
 70 sec: 0 operations; 
 80 sec: 0 operations; 
 90 sec: 0 operations; 
 100 sec: 0 operations; 
...
```

Clearly,there is no data loaded into Hbase.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

check for _hTable.setAutoFlush(true); is it set or not?

Also, com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient => you may try to run it as a java application, in case any issue happening related to HBase configuration or written methods.  I did modify com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient while doing performance benchmarking for Kundera. Above mentioned approach worked for me.

Hope it helps,

-Vivek

Comment: Thanks, I looked into the load.dat file and find the problem is that ycsb can't link to zookeeper, then I changed the command to :
java -cp build/ycsb.jar:db/hbase/lib/*:db/hbase/conf com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -load -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=family -p recordcount=5000 -s > load.dat
It then worked.Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that YCSB is using older version of Hbase.

To solve this issue, open pom.xml in YCSB folder and write the correct hbase version

```
<hbase.version>0.98.6.1-hadoop2</hbase.version>
```

also open YCSB/hbase/pom.xml and replace

```
<artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
```

by

```
<artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
```

Now just rebuild YCSB

```
mvn clean package
```